# Matlab - Stepwise GLM with Categoricals

Tags: matlab, statistics, regression, linear-regression, glm

I have a table of 85 predictors, some of which are numerical, logical, ordinal and nominal (hot-one encoded). They are predicting a single `finalScore` outcome var which ranges from 0 to 1. I'm running a stepwise GLM using:

`% model2 = stepwiseglm(predictors, finalScore);`

Each predictor's header indicates which of the four types it is and I'm wondering if there is a way to tell the model that there are these different types. [This page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/stepwiselm.html) suggests there is for categoricals but so far I have not found anything within each of the 4 types I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [Generalized Linear Models walk-through](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/generalized-linear-regression.html)

> For a table or dataset array tbl, fitting functions assume that these
>   data types are categorical
>
> - Logical
> - Categorical (nominal or ordinal)
> - Character array

As long as the data is represented by the appropriate types in the input table, you shouldn't have to specify any further. To ensure this you can typecast  nominal with `categorical()`, ordinal with `ordinal()`, and logical with `logical()`.

You can specify categorical vs non-categorical with `stepwiseglm(...'CategoricalVars',[0 1 0 1 0 0 0 ...]);` but if you typecast your input correctly this should be redundant anyways.

Once the model is built, you can verify that categorical variables and ranges are handled appropriately by checking `model2.VariableInfo`